# Total execution time exceed sum of each process

Tags: operating-system

I am currently learning about operation systems and I stumbled upon a question that I have yet to find an answer to. Given a multiprogrammed system containing a single core with N processes each with execution times t1, t2, t3, .... , Tn would it be possible for T(Total time) to exceed the sum of each individual process?

```
So is it possible that T > t1+t2+t3+....+tn ?
```

I do understand that running programs concurrently will reduce the amount of time to a minimum of T = max(t1,t2,t3, ... , tn), this is done by having 1 large process going between CPU bursts and I/O bursts. The other processes would be relatively small and would use either the CPU or I/O when the main process isn't, thus reducing the time to only the long process. The question is purely theoretical and doesn't apply to any particular OS.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by total time T? total time of what?

Comment: Total time of execution of all the processes. Lets say t1 is 15 time units (regarless of what they are) t2 is 15 units, t3 is 15 units. I would need to find a case where T (total time of all processes to execute) > than t1+t2+t3. T > t1+t2+t3 ; T > 15+15+15 ; T> 45 time units